# Use nerdctl to bind mount volume on Windows

Tags: containerd, nerdctl

I am trying to use `nerdctl run` command and bind mount a volume for a Windows container (nanoserver version 1809). Below are the containerd and nerdctl versions and the commands that I have tried, with the console output:

```
PS C:\> containerd -v
containerd github.com/containerd/containerd v1.6.8 9cd3357b7fd7218e4aec3eae239db1f68a5a6ec6
PS C:\> nerdctl -v
nerdctl version 0.23.0

PS C:\> nerdctl run -it --rm -v "C:\:C:\Host" nano:1809 cmd.exe
time="2022-09-23T17:16:47-07:00" level=fatal msg="failed to parse \"C:\\\\:C:\\\\Host\""
PS C:\> nerdctl run -it --rm -v "/:/Host/" nano:1809 cmd.exe
time="2022-09-23T17:16:53-07:00" level=warning msg="expected an absolute path, got a relative path \"/\" (allowed for nerdctl, but disallowed for Docker, so unrecommended)"
time="2022-09-23T17:16:53-07:00" level=fatal msg="expected an absolute path, got \"/Host/\""
```

Can anyone kindly let me know how I can start a container using containerd as runtime? Should I try to use `ctr` or `crictl` for bind mounting volumes in Windows for Windows containers? Kindly point me to a solution.